# UIControlEventEditingChanged doesn't get fired when using setText of UITextfield

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I am currently trying to track the states of a textfield.

I am using a custom datePicker which sets the text via `-setText`

```
[self.textField setText:[self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date]];
```

Inside my *textFieldDelegate* I wrote the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.travelToOnTextField.delegate = self;
  [self.travelToOnTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(travelToOnTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

-(void)travelToOnTextFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"Event Handler called");
}
```

If I change the text through my custom Datepicker the Method `travelToOnDateTextFieldDidChange` doesn't get called. But if I change the text using my Computer Keyboard it gets called for some reason.

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had to rate this question up because this is *super* important.

It appears this has changed in iOS6.  Maybe even iOS5.  This event **USED** to be the preferred method for observing text changes in a UITextField.  I've been using it since iOS3.  After recompiling my app on iOS6 to perform some updates, it mysteriously stopped working.  Parts of my app use:

```
[UITextField insertText];
```

and others use

```
[UITextField setText];
```

or

```
UITextField.text = @"xxx";
```

For whatever reason it's important to note that ***setText*** events no longer fire the Editing Changed event.  If you use an insertText method, it still works.

So if you're in a bind and you just need a quick fix, you can change out your code from:

```
textField.text;
```

or

```
[textField setText:@"xxx"];
```

to

```
textField.text = @"";
[textField insertText:@"new text"];
```

This also works:

```
[((UITextField*)view) sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

I hope this helps someone, because I wasted an entire day trying to figure out why this code suddenly stopped working when I moved up to iOS6.

You can still use NSNotificationCenter as well.  See the UITextField reference for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i also ended up using the sendActionsForControlEvents Method.

Comment: insertText doesn't work. But `[textField sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]` works.

Comment: `insertText(_:)` should work only if the text field is first responder because the documentation of `UIKeyInput` says it inserts text at the cursor position.

Answer (score 19):

Just call `sendActionsForControlEvents:` after you set the text:

```
self.textField.text = xxx;
[self.textField sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Tested on iOS 9.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 2.2+, based on @Shaolo's answer

1. Connect IBAction, pay attention to change default event type to `EditingChanged`

[image]

2. After you change textField's text  from code, add also sendActionsLine

   ```
   taskTextField.text = nil
   taskTextField.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

**Update: Swift 4.2**

```
textField.text = "some Text"
textField.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says:

> ```
> UIControlEventEditingChanged 
> A touch making an editing change in a UITextField objet. 
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later. 
> Declared in UIControl.h.
> ```

So **touch** only?