# Trigger textFieldShouldClear programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

If I understand correctly, the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldClear` gets triggered once the user taps on the clear button/icon provided with and enabled for a `UITextField`. But I need to clear the `UITextField` programmatically, which, in the absence of a clear method for UITextField (that I could find), I am doing like so:

```
textField.text = @"";
```

The above, however, does not trigger the `textFieldShouldClear` delegate method that I need. Any ideas how I could do it?

Alternatively, does my call above trigger any other delegate method? I checked, and `textInputChanged` is not called in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing `UITextField` and implementing the following method:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {

    [super setText:text];

    [self textInputChanged:nil];
}
```

Where `textInputChanged:` is the `UITextFieldDelegate` method that I needed to get called whenever text is set programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

TextField delegate methods will not fire if you set the text programmatically.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140087/uicontroleventeditingchanged-doesnt-get-fired-when-using-settext-of-uitextfield)

You can probably just perform whatever logic needs to be done after your `textField.text = @"";` line though, right?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the relevant answer, it helped me figure out the solution that suited my situation - adding it as an answer